# Nvidia Nsight 3 with OpenGL 3.3 error: Thisversion of OpenGL does not support capabilities

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, opengl, nsight

If I start graphic debugging with Nsight 3 I get the following error:

"This version of OpenGL does not support capabilities and extensions required by Nsight."

Which OpenGL version should I use? Up to now I use glut (3.7) with glew (1.9) on OpenGl 3.3. I can see the first frame and then the application crash (as you can see in uploaded pictures). If I debug one of my DirectX applications it works.

[image: first frame is visible]
[image: error info]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to "Graphics Inspector and Graphics Debugger" section in http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/3.0/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Release_Notes_Main.htm.